# Returning unique_ptr private member data without transferring ownership

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

**Context**

The error below appears to be telling me that I can not return my `unique_ptr` called `m_head` from this get function. I just want to return my `unique_ptr` `m_head` without transferring ownership.

I've been avoiding raw pointers completely since introduced to smart pointers since raw pointers are not exception safe, have the memory management overhead and other issues I've been aware of. Maybe there are cases like this where I should use them briefly contained in a small scope?

In this I think instead of my current approach I need to transfer ownership. I should instead get the object managed by the `unique_ptr`, create a new `shared_ptr` to manage the object, then return the `shared_ptr`, but need some confirmation. I think this may be the case because the [std::unique_ptr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/) docs say:

> unique_ptr objects own their pointer uniquely: no other facility shall
>   take care of deleting the object, and thus no other managed pointer
>   should point to its managed object, since as soon as they have to,
>   unique_ptr objects delete their managed object **without taking into**
>   **account whether other pointers still point to the same object or not,**
>   **and thus leaving any other pointers that point there as pointing to an**
>   **invalid location**.

**Error**

```
 `function "std::unique_ptr<_Ty, _Dx>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty, _Dx> &) 
 [with _Ty=mrobsmart::LinkedList::Node, _Dx=std::default_delete<mrobsmart::LinkedList::Node>]" 

 (declared at line 2337 of "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\include\memory")

 cannot be referenced  -- it is a deleted function
```

**Code**

```
#include <memory>

class LinkedList
{
    private:
        std::unique_ptr<Node> m_head;

    public:
        LinkedList(int data) {
            m_head = std::make_unique<Node>(data);
        }

        const std::unique_ptr<Node> get_head() { return m_head; }
};
```

Comment: 2 options: return by reference or just return a  (non-owning) raw pointer.

Comment: @skeller I'd to like re explore raw pointers. I've heard a lot of negative opinions about ever using raw pointers again since smart pointers have been introduced, but in cases like this it's okay to use a raw pointer? Are there any more cases where using raw pointers may be preferred over smart pointers?.

Comment: Raw pointers are completely exception safe as long as they don't **own** the object they are pointing to. In your case the `std::unique_ptr` owns it (deletes it) so returning a raw pointer is not evil and is exception safe.

Comment: How do you specify that a pointer owns an object? Would a raw pointer be considered the owner of an object if it is the only pointer to that object?

Comment: the owing is basically "by convention". A best practice is ownership always in a unique or shared pointer. that way you "know" all raw pointers are non-owing (never call delete on it). If used that way, raw pointer are perfectly fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I just want to return my unique_ptr m_head without transferring ownership.

That's not possible. `unique_ptr` is designed around the behavior that every move transfers its ownership.

> Note, I've been avoiding raw pointers completely since introduced to smart pointers since raw pointers are not exception safe, have the memory management overhead and other issues I've been aware of, but maybe there are cases like this where I should use them briefly contained in a small scope?

Raw pointers are not evil. Using them as pure references/indirections is a perfectly valid use case -- there is no ownership, memory management or exception safety involved.

Of course, it's also possible to return a C++ reference. Whether you choose a pointer or a reference can depend on whether the value can be null, but ultimately is also a question of code style.

So, either of those (important: `const`-qualify the function):

```
    const Node* get_head() const { return m_head.get(); }
    const Node& get_head() const { return *m_head; }
```

Comment: "as pure references/indirections is a perfectly valid use case -- there is no ownership, memory management or exception safety involved" Perfect I will implement this. Curious as to why 2 `const` keywords are in use to qualify the functions?

Comment: The first one is part of the return type: `const Node*` or `Node const*` means "pointer to const-qualified Node" (the node can't be modified through this pointer). The second one states that the member function does not modify the `this` object.

Comment: Does not modify the `this` object ... and therefore can be called on a const object.

Answer (score 1):

The "problem behind the problem" may be that you're trying to use a `unique_ptr` in a case where you shouldn't. I agree that one should avoid raw pointers, but there are options other than raw vs. unique pointers.

Two important properties of `std::unique_ptr` are:

1. The ability to represent a value which is not set (i.e. `null`).
2. The ability to transfer ownership.

If you don't need either, you are best served with storing the `Node` value directly in `m_head`, i.e.:

```
#include <memory>

class LinkedList
{
    private:
        Node m_head;

    public:
        LinkedList(int data) : m_head(data) {}

        const Node& get_head() { return m_head; }
};
```

If the code example is a simplified version of the real scenario in which `m_head` can be "not set", we would need a different solution, e.g. `std::optional`.

`std::optional` and `std::unique_ptr` both can represent a value being not set. However, `std::optional` does not support ownership transfer.

If you want to prevent ownership transfer, using a type which makes such impossible is a great way to communicate your intention to your colleagues and your future self. The code would change to:

```
#include <memory>

class LinkedList
{
    private:
        std::optional<Node> m_head;

    public:
        LinkedList(int data) : m_head(Node(data)) {}

        // some other code which can cause m_head to be empty

        const std::optional<Node> get_head() { return m_head; }
};
```

Comment: Perhaps you could shortly note or explain, why beside different kind of pointers, `optional` and storing the value directly are alternatives on equal footing. And why there are transcending properties/principles (like can represent a value) over all of those diverse solutions. I think a beginner could be confused or surprised that the solution space is larger than raw pointer, `unique_ptr`, `shared_ptr` and perhaps references, but the added solutions have comparable properties to pointers nevertheless.